# How do I assign multiple UI's to a parameter, such as both UILabels and UIButtons?

Tags: swift, parameters

I am trying to create a function that flips a `UILabel`, `UIButton`, etc. 180 degrees so that it is upside down. My problem is that I cannot find a way to give the function a parameter that is assigned to `UILabel`s, `UIButton`s, etc.

I have tried using "Any" to assign to my parameter, but `Any` does not have the method transform.

Here is my code so far without the parameter having anything assigned:

```
func rotate180(object: ) {

object.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngle: 3.14)

{
```

Comment: let me kow if it resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also implement this as an extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func rotate180() {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.14)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myButton.rotate180()
myLabel.rotate180()
myView.rotate180()
```